# loading the object in another view

Tags: iphone

I have a viewcontroller in which i have name and dob as string ,when a user clicks on submit button,the strings value should go to the prevoius controller for displaying...

For this i have made a .h and .m class and it's object is collecting the value in that class's object but how to pass the value to other controller from that object...

Here is the code below.....

after pressing the submit button,

```
objFrndDetails.frndName=self.txtFriendName.text;
objFrndDetails.frndDob=self.txtDOB.text;
```

here objFrndDetails is the object of my new .h amd .m class....

now.pLease help me...to pass the value i

Answer (score 0):

Use Delegation pattern.
Set the AddViewController' delegate to your DisplayViewController.
then call the delegate method to pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this make a protocol and delgate of the viewcontroller in which you set the value and when you are going to load this viewcontroller call viewcontroller.delegate=self;
and when you pressed button call the delegate method
if you want to more detail then i will post here.

Answer (score 0):

In .h file of anotherView

```
-(id)initUserInfo:(NSString *)friendName string:(NSString *)friendDOB;
```

In .m file of anotherView

```
-(id)initUserInfo:(NSString *)friendName string:(NSString *) friendDOB{

if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"nextView" bundle:nil]) {
    frndName =friendName;
    frndDob=friendDOB;
}
return self;
}
```

In .m File of firstView

```
-(IBAction)btnNext_TouchUpInside:(id)sender{
nextView *second =[[nextView alloc]initUserInfo:txtFriendName.text string:txtDOB.text];
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:NO];
}
```